# React.Children.toArray can't find props on children using typescript

Tags: reactjs, typescript

Typescript can't detect props object on children using React.Children.toArray
I have to use any[] because if I use ReactChild[] - props is not detected on an array item. How do I correctly type this out?
Thanks!

```
const items: any[] = React.Children.toArray(this.props.children)

// select whatever item was told to be onload first
const itemPaymentType = items[0].props['data-payment']
```

[image]

Answer (score 15):

casieber answer is correct.

but in order to access your props with typescript, this is needed:

```
const item = items[0];
if (React.isValidElement<{prop1: boolean}>(item)) {

    // item.props.prop1 -- works
}
```

Comment: Perfect! Thank you so much. Very Helpful as well!

Comment: I'd say this is the correct answer, thanks a lot!

Answer (score 9):

Typescript is doing the right thing here. Take a look at the typings definition for ReactChild:

```
type ReactChild = ReactElement<any> | ReactText;
```

where `ReactText` is typed as `string | number`.

By saying `const items: ReactChild[]` you are telling TypeScript that `items` is an array that has elements that are possibly strings. Obviously, a string does not have `props` as a property, and so it is complaining, rightly so, when you try and use `props`.

If you are certain that your component's children will only ever be true elements containing the prop types you are looking for, then you can type the output as `ReactElement<P>` where `P` is the prop types you expect. However, doing so is essentially casting something that you haven't guaranteed. A better way might be to allow TypeScript type inference to come into play through somethign like the following:

```
const items = React.Children.toArray(this.props.children); // Will be ReactChild[]

const item = items[0];
if (typeof item === 'string' || typeof item === 'number') {
    console.error('Expecting component children to be of type ...');
} else {
    // At this point, TypeScript will know that item must be of type ReactElement
    // since you have already taken care of the number and string case
    const itemPaymentType = item.props['data-payment'];
    // ...
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much for explaining this. It all makes sense, however I still get the error that props does not exist on type ReactChild. Property does not exist on type string